# Gridview isn't visible in runtime

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Gridview isn't visible in runtime, I haven't set visible property too.

Any suggestion?

My code is :

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


  Dim sqlCnn As SqlConnection
        Dim sqlCmd As SqlCommand
        Dim sql As String
        Dim sda As SqlDataAdapter

        Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=THERAIN\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Ashok;User ID=sa;Password=Ashok"
        sqlCnn = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        sql = "SELECT * FROM Income WHERE date>='" + TextBox1.Text.ToString + "' and date<='" + TextBox2.Text.ToString + "'"

        sda = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlCnn)

        sqlCnn.Open()

        Dim ds As New DataSet

        Dim commandBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(sda)

        sda.Fill(ds)
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Income")
        sqlCnn.Close()
        GridView1.Visible = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have to bind the grid as such: GridView1.DataBind() or are you doing that else where?

Comment: Is your gridview in a ajax panel or does the button clikc cause a full postback? Please show front end code where your grid markup is at

Comment: It would help us if you provided the markup for your GridView. It's also a good idea to set the EmptyDataText property so you know when your GridView is empty.

Comment: <div class="container">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
            <EmptyDataTemplate>No data found</EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    </div>

Comment: Also added GridView1.DataBind() after GridView1.DataSource

Comment: Thanks guys, it has been sorted out, I've created new page and added all controls again, after adding GridView1.DataBind() it got sorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes do a:

```
GridView1.DataBind()
```

After the datasource set.

Comment: Thank you very much Magnus, it has been sorted out now.